# scrolling text in the mode-line

Tags: mode-line, text-properties

Since the mode-line space is precious, I'd like to display some information in a fixed size area (60 char for example).

To do so, I'd like the text to scroll, like when music players display music title (that's actually what I want to do).

How can I do this ?

Comment: EMMS shows text scrolling in the mode-line. Have a look to the 'emms-mode-line-cycle.el' source code (https://github.com/momomo5717/emms-mode-line-cycle)